# What is the difference between a 3G router and a "classic" router?

Tags: router, 3g, usb-modem

I've seen a lot of 3G router and all of them requires a USB 3G modem to work.

But basically, any router who has a USB port could handle a USB modem, no ?
There is no specific hardware in a 3G router, as all the "3G part" is in the USB modem, right ?

So, what is the difference between a 3G router and a "classic" router ?

Comment: Many routers have USB ports for external storage or printers... Which can't be used for networking devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many routers have USB ports, but most of these are for other purposes:

- USB shared printer
- Eternal storage (quasi-NAS)
- Webcams
- etc

3G routers may also have USB ports specifically designed (and located on the WAN side) to handle 3G modems.

Related article : http://www.pcworld.com/article/225229/dlink_router_usb_port.html